# Intercepting a HTTP request in the middle of a test in Testcafe

Tags: testing, automated-tests, testcafe, functional-testing

I am writing a functional test using Testcafe. The test scenario is as below,
**There is a toggle button that activates/deactivates based on an API call**

When I open my application, an API call is made that returns a value ON/OFF; based on that, the toggle switch is activated or deactivated.

> **I want to intercept that call when the user clicks on that toggle button again.**

Long story short:

- User logs in
- XYZ API is called made, and it gives the response ON
- Based on that response, the toggle button is activated
- Then user will click on the toggle button
- Now the XYZ API should be called again which will return OFF

````
    await t.navigateTo(`${url}`);
    await t
        .click(myPage.toggleSwitch)
    .addRequestHooks(myPage.xyzAPI.respond([{ valueBar: "ON" }
    ]))
    .expect(myPage.toggleSwitch.checked)
    .eql(true);

});```
````

Answer (score 1):

> I want to intercept that call when the user clicks on that toggle button again.

You need to add the target request hook before the `click` action. Also, before the `click` action, the actions chain should be broken.

```js
    await t.navigateTo(`${url}`);

    await t.addRequestHooks(<hook that caught the API calls>);
    
    await t
        .click(myPage.toggleSwitch)
    .expect(myPage.toggleSwitch.checked).eql(true);
```